# split indented data based on preceding whitespace using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have recieved some data in the format shown here:

```
lvl1 - desc
    lvl2 - desc
    lvl2 - desc
        lvl3 - desc
        lvl3 - desc
        lvl3 - desc
            lvl4 - desc
            lvl4 - desc
```

The levels are indented by multiples of 4 whitespaces (4,8,12,etc...) with some descriptive text.
Can someone show me a method to split this single column into multiple columns based on the preceding whitespace?
The output should look like this:

```
lvl1 - desc
                     lvl2 - desc
                     lvl2 - desc
                                         lvl3 - desc
                                         lvl3 - desc
                                         lvl3 - desc
                                                             lvl4 - desc
                                                             lvl4 - desc
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by split into multiple columns: split level and desc into two different columns or make the level the columns and the desc the values

Comment: Hi Chris, I would like to have each level shown in a seperate column. So lvl1 in column 'A', lvl2 in column 'B' and so on.

Comment: Can you provide your expected output?

Comment: Hi Chris - I've updated the question. The input data is a 'bill of materials' for some drawing data. It has been provided to me with items at different levels all in one long column - using whitespace to indent to show the different levels. We would like to see each level in a seperate column so that we can filter the data in excel eventually.

Comment: Your expected output is the exact same as the input... please format

Comment: Apologies, I’m writing this on an old iPhone 5 - I hope the edit makes the question clearer. Imagine this going into an excel book. I would like to keep the different levels in the same row they are currently in - just split the output into columns so it could be filtered. I.e. level 1 (including description) in column A, level 2 in column B, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you look for something like this:

```
# sample data
s = """lvl1 - desc1
    lvl2 - desc2
    lvl2 - desc3
        lvl3 - desc4
        lvl3 - desc5
        lvl3 - desc6
            lvl4 - desc7
            lvl4 - desc8"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), header=None)

# strip whitespace
df[0] = df[0].str.strip()
# groupby the first 4 characters of the string then apply list
# convert to array then back to a DataFrame and transpose
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(df[0].str[:4])[0].apply(list).values.tolist()).T

              0             1             2             3
0  lvl1 - desc1  lvl2 - desc2  lvl3 - desc4  lvl4 - desc7
1          None  lvl2 - desc3  lvl3 - desc5  lvl4 - desc8
2          None          None  lvl3 - desc6          None
```

Comment: Thanks Chris - This is exactly what I was looking for! apologies for the massively delayed response - I managed to figure out a method myself - but it was so long ago I can't really remember my method!